# Turn off flyspell mode for Greek and Hebrew but not English

Tags: org-mode, flyspell

I have flyspell activated for certain document types, e.g. `txt` and `org`. If I want to turn off flyspell for a specific document, I add `# -*- eval: (flyspell-mode -1); -*-` to the top of the file. This works only well for documents typed in English. I would like to instruct flyspell never to check spelling for Greek or Hebrew text. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean Greek or Hebrew embedded inside a document with English text?  If so, you can't (easily). Else... add that line to the top of the documents in those languages. Of course could also have a lang specific postfix in the naming conventions and detect that in an open file hook to determine whether to turn on flyspell or not. I'm not aware of any flyspell feature where it can guess the language in specific paragraphs.

Comment: I mean I don't need flyspell for any language other than English and what to turn it off for those other languages. All my documents are default English, but yes, there are other embedded languages also.

Comment: It cant guess your language. So occam's razor. Either embed that line with the local setting for the mode or bind a key to toggle flyspell on/off.  eg (global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'flyspell-mode) will do it.

Comment: The thing is I want to keep flyspell on for English. Just turn it off for Greek and Hebrew.